# Cannot install jpegoptim on Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, libjpeg

I am trying to install jpegoptim on a CentOS 6 server. I have downloaded and unpacked the package but when I try to run ./configure from the jpegoptim-1.3.0 directory I get an error that says:

"cannot find libjpeg or you have too old version (v6 or later required)."

I have checked and I have libjpeg-turbo install, which should supercede libjpeg. I have not been able to find anything on the net about this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configure script is looking for jpeglib.h which is in the libjpeg-turbo-devel package.

Comment: That was the issue -- I needed to install libjpeg-turbo-devel. The bad news: After running jpegoptim on my image folder, none of the images will display. Don't know what happened there. Thank God I've got another copy of the folder on my main system at hope. Criminy! The images are still there -- could this be a permissions issue?

Comment: That's what it was -- a permissions problem. jpegoptim changed the permissions and I had to reset it.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use yum to help you with what you are looking for. The following may get you what you need:

```
yum search libjpeg
yum install libjpeg*
```

Note I have the epel repository installed on my system too. So if the above don't give you what you want, you may need to install the epel repository first.